# User variable storage ($PATH etc) in Windows

Tags: windows, environment-variables

On windows system, we have `system variables` (including `$Path`) and `user variables` (including a `$Path` too); (equivalents to `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` in the bash case).

Where are those definitions are stored ? In particular the user variables.
The goal is to recover them from a backup.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/environment-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stored in the registry.

User variables are in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment and system variables are in [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/environment-variables).

If all you have is a backup, HKEY_CURRENT_USER is stored in the NTUSER.DAT file in the users profile directory and you can [load this file in Regedit](https://web.archive.org/web/20200707153619/http://www.zeda.nl/index.php/en/load-user-registry-hive-in-regedit).

Comment: (broken link 'load file in Regedit')

Comment: @guthrie fixed...